# Read string in HDF5/C++

Tags: python, c++, hdf5

I have stored a string (and a vector) in my HDF5 archive, for example with the Python interface:

```
import h5py

file = h5py.File("example.h5","w")

file['/path/to/vector'] = [0., 1., 2.]
file['/path/to/string'] = 'test'
```

Now I want the read the string to a `std::string`. I know how to read the vector (see below), but I have absolutely no idea how to read the string. *What particularly don't understand is how to allocate the result*, as:

- The H5Cpp library does not seem to use the STL-containers, but rather raw pointers, requiring pre-allocation.
- This is somewhat contradicted by the observation HDFView indicates the dimension size to be `1` and the type to be "String, length = variable".

Here is how I read the vector:

```
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // open file
  H5::H5File fid = H5::H5File("example.h5",H5F_ACC_RDONLY);

  // open dataset
  H5::DataSet   dataset    = fid.openDataSet("/path/to/vector");
  H5::DataSpace dataspace  = dataset.getSpace();
  H5T_class_t   type_class = dataset.getTypeClass();

  // check data type
  if ( type_class != H5T_FLOAT )
    throw std::runtime_error("Unable to read, incorrect data-type");

  // check precision
  // - get storage type
  H5::FloatType datatype = dataset.getFloatType();
  // - get number of bytes
  size_t precision = datatype.getSize();
  // - check precision
  if ( precision != sizeof(double) )
    throw std::runtime_error("Unable to read, incorrect precision");

  // get the size
  // - read rank (a.k.a number of dimensions)
  int rank = dataspace.getSimpleExtentNdims();
  // - allocate
  hsize_t hshape[rank];
  // - read
  dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims(hshape, NULL);
  // - total size
  size_t size = 0;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < rank ; ++i ) size += static_cast<size_t>(hshape[i]);

  // allocate output
  std::vector<double> data(size);

  // read data
  dataset.read(const_cast<double*>(data.data()), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);

  // print data
  for ( auto &i : data )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

(compiled with `h5c++ -std=c++14 so.cpp`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // open file
  H5::H5File fid = H5::H5File("example.h5",H5F_ACC_RDONLY);

  // open dataset, get data-type
  H5::DataSet   dataset    = fid.openDataSet("/path/to/string");
  H5::DataSpace dataspace  = dataset.getSpace();
  H5::StrType   datatype   = dataset.getStrType();

  // allocate output
  std::string data;

  // read output
  dataset.read(data, datatype, dataspace);

  std::cout << data << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried emulating this code but I'm only getting the first character of the string being returned from the dataset.read call.